# simple REST call from Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, rest, getjson

I am trying to call my service from here
 http://diningphilospher.azurewebsites.net/api/dining

using below javascript,

```
$.ajax(
{
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    url: "http://diningphilospher.azurewebsites.net/api/dining/",
    success: function (data) 
    {
        alert(data);
    }
});
```

But I am getting error relating cross origin. I see people suggest using JSONP but I guess my server does not support JSONP. I studied CORS and could not understand the head or tail of it. I would like to know the way around to read the JSON that sits in different domain.

Comment: What do you not understand about CORS? What server are you running? I pretty sure it can handle json.

Comment: @Musa, Currently if i use this I get CORS error. How to fix that. I was told to add a Access-Control-Request-Allow-method as part of request. I cannot find a simple working example. All i see is W3C docs. Is there a links showing how to enable CORS in client side through examples

Comment: Try adding this `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` http header.

Comment: url is outputting xml not json or jsonp. As far as server supporting jsonp... jsonp is just text output that is parsed by browser as script

Comment: @charlietfl great catch. you are right, I am now working to remove the default formatter from xml to json.hope it works

Answer (score 1):

I hope this should work:

```
$.ajax(
{
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    url: "http://diningphilospher.azurewebsites.net/api/dining/",
    success: function (data) 
    {
        alert(data);
    }
});
```

Or just add/append **?callback=?** along with your cross-domain url.